# How to index deleted in acts_as_paranoid rows in sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, acts-as-paranoid

I'm using sunspot and acts_as_paranoid gems in ruby on rails application.

When i'm deleting a record, acts_as_paranoid gem overrides ActiveRecord behaviour not no delete it, but update `deleted_at` field to not-null value. And by defaults, add to all AR queries `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` scipe.

I have a lot of deleted users. And in adminpanel page I need to view and search them.

The problem is that when reindexing `User` model, sunspot not indexing deleted users at all (adding `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` scope by default).

The only chance to index it, is to manually run

```
User.with_deleted.solr_reindex
```

So, the question is: how I should change my code, that sunspot **ALWAYS** index deleted records in `User` model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string  :class_name do
      self.class.name
    end

    integer(:model_id) { |user| user.id }
    integer :community_ids, references: 'Community', multiple: true

   # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```